# Check if item in sublist exists in other sublists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

What am I doing wrong? I am trying to find out if people in the same group are in the same group in groups.

```
X = int(input())

sameGroup = []
groups = []

violations = 0

for i in range(X):
    sameName = input().split()
    sameGroup.append(sameName)
for i in range(X):
    group = input().split()
    groups.append(group)

for i in range(len(sameGroup)):
    names = sameGroup[i]
    print(names)
    for i in range(len(groups)):
        if names in groups[i]:
            print("yo")
            violations += 1

print(violations)
```

input:

```
2
hello Hi
Hel hooo
Hello Hi yoo
helloo heee haaa
```

output:

```
['hello', 'Hi']
['Hel', 'hooo']
0
```

Expected output
1

Comment: There is a very handy thing called a "set" in python. You make a set like: `s = set()` and then you can add to it like `s.add(input())` and then to check if there is an intersection between sets you can just check something like `s1.instersection(s2)` (where s1 and s2 are your sets). https://realpython.com/python-sets/

Comment: I recommend [Getting started](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/)

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do, can you give a clearer example input (like names instead of `helloo heee haaa`) and full expected output?

Answer (score 0):

your question is unclear to me , but I'll give a try :

```
X = int(input())

sameGroup = []
groups = []

violations = 0

for i in range(X):
    sameName = input().split()
    sameGroup.append(sameName)
for i in range(X):
    group = input().split()
    groups.append(group)
    
print('sameGroup : ' , sameGroup , type(sameGroup))
print('groups : ' , groups , type(groups))

for i in range(len(sameGroup)):
    names = sameGroup[i]
    print('names : ' , names)
    for i in range(len(groups)):
        if names == groups[i]:
            print("yo")
            violations += 1

print(violations)
```

Input :

```
2
1 2
3 4
5 6
1 2
```

Output :

```
sameGroup :  [['1', '2'], ['3', '4']] <class 'list'>
groups :  [['5', '6'], ['1', '2']] <class 'list'>
names :  ['1', '2']
yo
names :  ['3', '4']
1
```

I just changed `if names in  groups[i]:` to `if names == groups[i]:` , see code below :

```
X = int(input())

sameGroup = []
groups = []

violations = 0

for i in range(X):
    sameName = input().split()
    sameGroup.append(sameName)
for i in range(X):
    group = input().split()
    groups.append(group)
    
print('sameGroup : ' , sameGroup , type(sameGroup))
print('groups : ' , groups , type(groups))

for i in range(len(sameGroup)):
    names = sameGroup[i]
    print('names : ' , names , id(names))
    for i in range(len(groups)):
        print('group[i] : ', groups[i] , id(groups[i]))
        if names == groups[i]:
            print("yo") , print('names in groups[i] : ', names in groups[i],
                
                '\nnames == group[i] : ', names == groups[i])
            violations += 1

print(violations)
```

Input :

```
2
1 2
3 4
1 2
5 6
```

Output:

```
sameGroup :  [['1', '2'], ['3', '4']] <class 'list'>
groups :  [['1', '2'], ['5', '6']] <class 'list'>
names :  ['1', '2'] 136133245194752
group[i] :  ['1', '2'] 136133245193280
yo
names in groups[i] :  False 
names == group[i] :  True
group[i] :  ['5', '6'] 136133245193536
names :  ['3', '4'] 136133245176640
group[i] :  ['1', '2'] 136133245193280
group[i] :  ['5', '6'] 136133245193536
1
```

More on that :

```
list1 = [['a' , 'b'], ['c' , 'd']]
 
list2 = [['a' , 'b'], ['e' , 'f']]
 
 
print('list1[0] in list2 : ' , list1[0] in list2)


print('list1[0] in list2[0] : ' , list1[0] in list2[0])


print('list1[0] == list2[0] : ' , list1[0] == list2[0])


list1 = [['a' , 'b'], ['c' , 'd']]
 
list2 = [['b' , 'a'], ['e' , 'f']]


print('list1[0] in list2 : ' , list1[0] in list2)


print('list1[0] in list2[0] : ' , list1[0] in list2[0])


print('list1[0] == list2[0] : ' , list1[0] == list2[0])

print('set(list1[0]) = ', set(list1[0]), ' in set(list2[0]) = ', set(list2[0]), ' : ' , set(list1[0]) in set(list2[0]))

print('set(list1[0]) = ', set(list1[0]), ' == set(list2[0]) = ', set(list2[0]), ' : ' , set(list1[0]) == set(list2[0]))
```

Output:

```
list1[0] in list2 :  True
list1[0] in list2[0] :  False
list1[0] == list2[0] :  True
list1[0] in list2 :  False
list1[0] in list2[0] :  False
list1[0] == list2[0] :  False
set(list1[0]) =  {'b', 'a'}  in set(list2[0]) =  {'b', 'a'}  :  False
set(list1[0]) =  {'b', 'a'}  == set(list2[0]) =  {'b', 'a'}  :  True
```